# Next-Auth & Vercel: [ CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR ]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 api/auth/providers

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth, t3

I keep receiving this error message on my Preview deployment on Vercel:

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 {
  error: {
    message: 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0',
    stack: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0\n' +
      '    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6498:19)\n' +
      '    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6472:27)\n' +
      '    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1145:60\n' +
      '    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7\n' +
      '    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:204:9)\n' +
      '    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
    name: 'SyntaxError'
  },
  url: 'https://[my-censored-domain-name].com/api/auth/providers',
  message: 'Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'
}
```

That JSON is:

```
{
   "google":{
      "id":"google",
      "name":"Google",
      "type":"oauth",
      "signinUrl":"https://[my-censored-domain-name].com/api/auth/signin/google",
      "callbackUrl":"https://[my-censored-domain-name].com/api/auth/callback/google"
   },
   "email":{
      "id":"email",
      "name":"Email",
      "type":"email",
      "signinUrl":"https://[my-censored-domain-name].com/api/auth/signin/email",
      "callbackUrl":"https://[my-censored-domain-name].com/api/auth/callback/email"
   }
}
```

Here's what I've tried:

- Set `NEXTAUTH_URL` to my custom domain name (not the vercel one)
- Set `NEXTAUTH_SECRET`
- Added `secret` to the `[...next-auth].ts` with `NEXTAUTH_SECRET`
- Temporarily added `NEXTAUTH_INTERNAL_URL = http://localhost:8080` to my env config
- Added `e.preventDefault()` in front of the `signIn()` calls

Could anyone help me with this? The `next-auth` docs say to set `NEXTAUTH_URL`, but it's clearly set on Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this issue, thanks to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4351#discussioncomment-5280125).

If your configuration is correct with Next Auth, you should disable "Deployment Protections" on Vercel. You may have to clear your cookies.